# s3fs complains about SSH key or SSL cert - how to fix?

Tags: linux, debian, amazon-s3, s3fs

I downloaded and installed [s3fs 1.73](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon) on my Debian Wheezy system. The specific steps I took were, all as root:

```
apt-get -u install build-essential libfuse-dev fuse-utils libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev mime-support
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

The installation went well and I proceeded to create a file `/usr/local/etc/passwd-s3fs` with my credentials copied from past notes (I'm pretty sure those are correct). That file is mode 0600 owner 0:0. Piecing together from the example on the web page and the man page, I then try a simple mount as a proof of concept to make sure everything works:

```
$ sudo -i
# s3fs mybucketname /mnt -o url=https://s3.amazonaws.com -o passwd_file=/usr/local/etc/passwd-s3fs
```

In short: it doesn't.

The mount point exists with reasonable permissions, and I get no error output from s3fs. However, nothing gets mounted on /mnt, `mount` has no idea about anything of the sort, and if I try `umount` it says about the directory "not mounted". The system logs say `s3fs: ###curlCode: 51  msg: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK`, but **how do I find out which SSL certificate it is talking about or in what way was it not OK?** Firefox has no complaints when I connect to that URL but also redirects me to https://aws.amazon.com/s3/.

**How do I get s3fs to actually work?**

Answer (score 0):

To fix it, you have to enable debug output. Add the following options to your `s3fs` mount command:

```
s3fs ... -f -d -o dbglevel=info -o curldbg
```

You will get a lot more info on what is going wrong, especially which check on your certificate fails.